# What does "send data to" a socket mean in this part of Beej's guide?

Tags: c, sockets, networking, send

Just getting into c network programming, and have been looking at Beej's guide. In the section on *send()* and *recv()* I came across this code:

```
int send(int sockfd, const void *msg, int len, int flags);
```

followed by this sentence:

"sockfd is the socket descriptor you want to send data to (whether it’s the one returned by socket() or the one you got with accept())."

The way I understand it, if sockfd is a stream socket, it's in a connected state. By "sockfd is the socket descriptor you want to send data to", does this mean the data is actually sent (by way of sockfd) to the *recv()* 'ing socket connected to sockfd?

Comment: The data is sent to the peer, yes. Whether they actually consume it with recv() is up to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `send()` (or `write()`, `writev()` etc) can be used to copy data to a peer via the open socket.  The peer can then use `recv()` (or `read()`, `readv()` etc) to obtain the data.